# Definition of Authorization according to OAuth2

Tags: authorization, oauth2, oidc

I am trying to understand OAuth2 and OIDC.   The [OIDC glossary](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Terminology) is a good starting point, and while it defines "Authentication", but does not actually define "Authorization".  I suspect it leaves to the OAuth2 specification to define the term.  I cannot, however, find any [definition in the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749).  Where is the official definition of "Authorization" according to OAuth2?

Comment: Why do you need a definition from a specific source? Is it not a general term?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "**Internet Security Glossary**" RFC 4949, indeed referenced by https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.references2, is what I was looking for:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4949.txt

> An approval that is granted to a system entity to access a system resource.

Comment: So, the general definition?